# Как заинжектить в kotlin'овские Object'ы с помощью Dagger2?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

У меня есть некий логгер, который при достижении определенного количества логов отправляет их на сервер.
Сам класс логгера это Object. Мне нужно заинжектить в него репозиторий.
Судя по этому вопросу:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413780/dagger-injection-not-working-for-object-in-kotlin
это сделать можно.

Application

```
сlass App : DaggerApplication(), HasServiceInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var serviceInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Service>

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return appComponentBuilder.application(this).build()
    }

    override fun serviceInjector(): DispatchingAndroidInjector<Service> {
        return serviceInjector
    }

    private object AppHolder {
        val INSTANCE = App()
    }

    companion object {
        val appComponentBuilder = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
        fun getInstance(): App {
            return AppHolder.INSTANCE
        }
    }
}
```

AppComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class, ActivityBindingModule::class, ServicesBindingModule::class, InteractorsModule::class, RepositoryModule::class, ToolsModule::class, AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder
        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

}
```

Logger

```
object Logger {

    @set:Inject
    lateinit var repository: Repository

    init {
        //How to inject????
    }

    private fun send() {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            repository.sendLogs(someLogs)
        }
    }

    ....

}
```

Что и куда нужно добавить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Созданием объектов и внедрением зависимостей занимается у вас даггер, поэтому стоит поручить создание синглтона `Logger` ему, а не делать это через котлин. Вы же свои репозитории не делаете `object`?

У вас даже есть отдельный `ToolsModule`. Можно провайдить `Logger` через него. Тогда `Logger` будет `class` и проблем с инжектом возникнуть не должно, ещё он будет синглтоном, как вы и хотели.